# Does PHP re-run functions if they in are in the top of a foreach?

Tags: php, loops

To clarify, If I have the following code:

```
foreach (range(1,10) as $value) {
    // do something
}
```

Will the function `range()` be used 10 times or does PHP save it's output for the duration of the loop? Also, what loops do/don't re-run functions?

I know that `while` loops **do** re-run functions, however for `foreach` loops it would make sense if they were not re-run each time.

**Why:** I am running through my code trying to eliminate redundant tasks

Comment: Why not test it yourself and find out?

Comment: It makes a copy of the results and it is run only once, but if you use `while(list($key, $value) = each(range(1,10))){` it will run it each time the loop comes back around.

Comment: Well, I didn't see any info on it in the docs, and testing each type of loop is tedious. I was hoping someone would know off-hand, or could point me to some documentation on the subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the function range() be used 10 times or does PHP save it's output for the duration of the loop?

The latter. PHP will call your function only once. PHP evaluates the part before `as`, stores its result, and iterates over.

**Proof:**

```
function foo() {
    global $counter;
    $counter++;
    return range(1, 10);
}

$counter = 0;
foreach (foo() as $key => $value) {}
printf("The function was executed %d time(s)\n", $counter);

$counter = 0;
$result = foo();
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {}
printf("The function was executed %d time(s)\n", $counter);
```

**Output:**

```
The function was executed 1 time(s)
The function was executed 1 time(s)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/135099)

Answer (score 0):

`range()` will run just once to get the value.

Try it yourself by moving `range(1,10)` into another function:

```
function getrange()
{
    error_log("running getrange()");
    return range(1,10);
}

foreach(getrange() as $val)
{
    ...
}
```

Now go look at the error log.